# How to create and add role in Hikari

Tags: discord

In Hikari (Python API for bots) how do you create and add roles (while specifying permissions)? I've already tried, but to no avail.

```
perms = (Permissions.READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY
     | Permissions.SPEAK
     | Permissions.CONNECT
     | Permissions.USE_VOICE_ACTIVITY)
```

muted = Role(name="muted", permissions=perms)

I've tried this, but i get an error saying I need some other kwargs, but i don't understand all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to create a `Role` object directly, instead you use the bots `rest` attribute to create it for you.

This is a working script that creates the a role called `custom-role` with the permissions you specified when you send a message in the guild with the content `$$create-role`.  Keep in mind this code will error if the bot does not have the MANAGE_ROLES permission, and you'll need to update the admin id's accordingly to be able to use the command youself.

The documentation for the create_role method can be found [here](https://www.hikari-py.dev/hikari/impl/rest.html#hikari.impl.rest.RESTClientImpl.create_role).

```py
import os
import hikari


bot = hikari.GatewayBot(os.environ["TOKEN"])
admin_ids = [1234, 5678, 9101] # These should ideally be stored in a database.

@bot.listen()
async def on_message(event: hikari.GuildMessageCreateEvent) -> None:
    if event.is_bot or not event.content:
        # Ignore bots and empty messages
        return None

    if event.author_id not in admin_ids:
        # Only allow admins to run this command
        return None

    if event.content.startswith("$$create-role"):
        # Create the role, with the permissions
        role = await bot.rest.create_role(
            event.guild_id,
            name="custom-role",
            permissions=(
                hikari.Permissions.READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY
                | hikari.Permissions.SPEAK
                | hikari.Permissions.CONNECT
                | hikari.Permissions.USE_VOICE_ACTIVITY
            )
        )

        # Send a message to the channel that we created the role
        await event.message.respond(f"Created new role <@&{role.id}>")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.run()
```